# How to compile glibc 32bit on an x86_64 machine

Tags: linux, glibc

I'm trying to compile glibc (as a secondary, not a system replacement) 2.6 on an x86_64, and trying to get it to produce 32-bit objects. When I give it a standard configure, it compiles fine, producing the usual 64-bit library objects. Some info:

> ```
> $ uname -a
> Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 20 07:32:21 \
> EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> $ cat /etc/redhat-release
> CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
> ```

Among other things, I've tried the following:

Attempt 1:

> ```
> $ # [in build/glibc-2.6]
> $ ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>                                 --with-cpu=i386-pc-linux-gnu
>
> ...
>
> checking sysdep dirs... configure: error: The i386-pc-linux-gnu
> subspecies of x86_64 is not supported."
> ```

Attempt 2:

> ```
> $ ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>                                 --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu
>
> ...
>
> $ make
> ```

The configure succeeds, but `make` causes a stream of compilation errors which all look like this:

> ```
> nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h:65:3: error: #error "TLS support is required."
> In file included from include/tls.h:6,
>                  from sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.h:30,
>                  from <stdin>:1:
> ```

I get the same result if I add --with-tls, and/or --target=i386-pc-linux-gnu.

[EDIT: It looks like I was confusing --target for --build. I tried adding --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu instead, and also for all of the other attempts where I tried --target. In all cases, I got exactly the same result as before.]

Attempt 3:

> ```
> $ CFLAGS=-m32 \
>   ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>                                 --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu \
>
> ... 
>
> In file included from ./../include/libc-symbols.h:55,
>                  from <command line>:1:
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/config.h:3:3: error: #error "glibc cannot be \
> compiled without optimization"
> ```

Again, the same thing happens with --with-tls

Attempt 4:

> ```
> $ CFLAGS="-m32 -O2" \
>   ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>                                 --host=i386-pc-linux-gnu \
>
> ... 
>
> gcc ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/sysdep.S -c  -I../include \
>     -I/home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/csu \
>     -I/home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6 -I../sysdeps/i386/elf \
>     -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 \
>     -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux \
>     -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/i386 \
>     -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix \
>     -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix \
>     -I../sysdeps/i386/fpu -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386 \
>     -I../sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 \
>     -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 \
>     -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 \
>     -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 \
>     -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic \
>     -I../nptl  -I.. -I../libio -I. \
>     -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h \
>     -DHAVE_INITFINI -DASSEMBLER \
>     -I/home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/csu/. -DGAS_SYNTAX \
>     -Wa,--noexecstack \
>     -o /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/csu/sysdep.o \
>     -MD -MP \
>     -MF /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/csu/sysdep.o.dt \
>     -MT /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/csu/sysdep.o
>
> ../sysdeps/unix/i386/sysdep.S: Assembler messages:
> ../sysdeps/unix/i386/sysdep.S:51: Error: @NTPOFF reloc is not supported \
> with 64-bit output format
> ../sysdeps/unix/i386/sysdep.S:51: Error: junk `@NTPOFF' after expression
> ```

I feel like this should be easier. Am I missing something?

If you need any more information, let me know and I'll provide it.

[EDIT]

Attempt 5 (suggested by EmployedRussian)

> ```
> $ ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>      CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" i686-linux-gnu
>
> ... 
>
> gcc -m32   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared \
>     -o /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/ld.so
>     -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs
>     /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os \
>     -Wl,--version-script=/home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/ld.map \
>     -Wl,-soname=ld-linux.so.2 \
>     -T /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/ld.so.lds
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os: In function `add_dependency':
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-lookup.c:106: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-lookup.c:110: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os: In function `_dl_profile_fixup':
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-runtime.c:196: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-runtime.c:205: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os: In function `_dl_fixup':
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-runtime.c:102: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-runtime.c:110: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os: In function `dl_open_worker':
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-open.c:425: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-open.c:427: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
> /home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/librtld.os: In function `_dl_close_worker':
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-close.c:407: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
> /home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf/dl-close.c:409: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [/home/USER/build/glibc32-2.6/elf/ld.so] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USER/src/glibc-2.6/elf'
> make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/USER/src/glibc-2.6'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

This time the build runs successfully for a long time before it reaches an error. I did a search and found something suggesting that I add a "-march" flag, which I did. This finally worked:

Attempt 6:

> ```
> $ ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
>      CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" \
>      CFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686" \
>      CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686" \
>      i686-linux-gnu
> ```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I edited the question, but then I realized the proper way is to add an answer. Here's what finally worked:

```
 $ ../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
     --host=i686-linux-gnu \
     --build=i686-linux-gnu \
     CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" \
     CFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686" \
     CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686"
```

I think putting `-m32` in CC and CXX instead of CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS was important because there was at least one compile operation during the make which didn't use CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS, and `-m32` absolutely has to always be there. Not sure why `-march=i686` was necessary (given the `-m32` parts and the `--host/build` options), but it was.

Comment: This worked for me as well with glibc-2.10.0 (32bit) on a 64bit host running Proxmox VE 2.2.

Comment: Today, with Glibc 2.23, I didn't need --build or -march (ergo no CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS).  As neither of these should be necessary, I presume some bug has been fixed since this question/answer.

Comment: my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS / kernel version: 4.4.0-31-generic works.

Answer (score 5):

Three important `./configure` flags:

- `--build=` The system performing the build.  Looks like yours is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.
- `--host=` The system on which the generated objects will be used.  You want to set this to `i386-pc-linux-gnu`.
- `--target=` If you are building a compiler, the system for which the built compiler will generate objects.

To perform a cross-compile, you must specify *both* `--build=` and `--host=`.  When you only specify `--host=`, it will still attempt to build a native (`x86_64`) glibc.

Comment: Thanks, I was confusing --target for --build. Unfortunately, when I redid all the tests I got the same results as before.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

```
../../src/glibc-2.6/configure --prefix=$HOME/glibc32-2.6 \
 CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" i686-linux-gnu
```

Comment: This build went much further than any of the others, but did eventually error out. I found a build which worked, however, by adding a few things to this. I'm still trying to figure out why it worked.