# gcc i686 on x86_64 platform

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

I have some troubles to install GCC i686 on a RHEL X86_64.
Indeed, I have to build some 32bit softwares and shared libraries on this platform.
I can build these softwares and libraries on 32bit platforms (linux or windows).

My questions are at the end of this post.

My first problem was this error: (during a buil, under eclipse -helios)

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314,
                  from ../../../../../XXXX.h:19,
                  from /XXXX.c:33: 
/usr/include/sys/types.h:150: error: duplicate 'unsigned' 
/usr/include/sys/types.h:151: error: duplicate 'unsigned' 
/usr/include/sys/types.h:151: error: duplicate 'short' 
/usr/include/sys/types.h:152: error: duplicate 'unsigned' 
/usr/include/sys/types.h:152: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers 
make: *** [XXXX.o] Error 1
```

To correct this error, I had to put the stdlib.h include before all the other files, but I have a lot of files, and sometimes this trick did not work anyway.
Moreover, I should not modify the source files.

I have exactly the same problem when I use a makefile given by a friend, to build a shared library.
This makefile works well on his platform (the same as me, RHEL 4.4.6 x86_64).

He told me the error appears because I use X86_64 lib, to build a 32bits software (or shared lib).

Here's my version of GCC :

```
GCC version

[root@localhost bin]# gcc -v
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr 
--mandir=/usr/share/man 
--infodir=/usr/share/info 
--with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla 
--enable-bootstrap 
--enable-shared 
--enable-threads=posix 
--enable-checking=release 
--with-system-zlib 
--enable-__cxa_atexit 
--disable-libunwind-exceptions 
--enable-gnu-unique-object 
--enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada 
--enable-java-awt=gtk 
--disable-dssi 
--with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre 
--enable-libgcj-multifile 
--enable-java-maintainer-mode 
--with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar 
--disable-libjava-multilib 
--with-ppl 
--with-cloog 
--with-tune=generic 
--with-arch_32=i686 
--build=x86_64-redhat-linux
thread: posix
gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) 

[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa |grep gcc
gcc-c++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
gcc-gfortran-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
```

So first, I installed glibc.i686 and libgcc.i686 packages from the RHEL DVD setup.
Now I have:

```
Installed packages (from redhat DVD)
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa |grep glibc
glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.12-1.47.el6.i686
glibc-headers-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.i686

[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa |grep libgcc
libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
```

Since GCC is x86_64, I read some documents about the cross compilation, espcially this one:
[wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Criss-Compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)

So I downloaded: gcc-4.4.6.tar.gz, binutils-2.23.tar.gz, gmp-5.0.2.tar.gz, and mpfr-3.1.1.tar.gz.
I put the directories gmp-5.0.2 and mpfr-3.1.1 in gcc-4.4.6 directory (and I renamed gmp-5.0.2 to gmp, and mpfr-3.1.1 to mpfr).

I followed the wiki.osdev instructions, that is:

```
export PREFIX=/usr/local/cross
export TARGET=i686-elf
cd /usr/src
mkdir build-binutils build-gcc
cd /usr/src/build-binutils
../binutils-x.xx/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --disable-nls
make all
make install
cd /usr/src/build-gcc
export PATH=$PATH:$PREFIX/bin
../gcc-x.x.x/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --disable-nls \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
make all-gcc
make install-gcc
```

- '**make all**' and '**make install**' for binutils => OK
- '**make all-gcc**'

--> 1st error: missing "mpfr.h" in "real.h". So I added mpfr.h in gcc-4.4.6/gcc and it was OK (maybe not actually ...)

--> 2nd error (the only one now):

```
[...]
gcc  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall 
-Wwrite-strings 
-Wstrict-prototypes 
-Wmissing-prototypes 
-Wcast-qual 
-Wold-style-definition 
-Wc++-compat 
-Wmissing-format-attribute 
-pedantic 
-Wno-long-long 
-Wno-variadic-macros 
-Wno-overlength-strings   
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H  
-o cc1-dummy c-lang.o stub-objc.o attribs.o c-errors.o c-lex.o c-pragma.o c-decl.o 
c-typeck.o c-convert.o c-aux-info.o c-common.o c-opts.o c-format.o c-semantics.o 
c-ppoutput.o c-cppbuiltin.o c-objc-common.o c-dump.o c-pch.o c-parser.o i386-c.o 
c-gimplify.o tree-mudflap.o c-pretty-print.o c-omp.o dummy-checksum.o \
              main.o  libbackend.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a   
-L/usr/src/build-gcc/./gmp/.libs -L/usr/src/build-gcc/./gmp/_libs 
-L/usr/src/build-gcc/./mpfr/.libs -L/usr/src/build-gcc/./mpfr/_libs 
-lmpfr -lgmp
**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpfr
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cc1-dummy] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/build-gcc/gcc'
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2**
```

**Finally, my questions are :

- Is this cross-compilation can resolve my problem ?
- What is the good way to resolve the problem of the missing ld mpfr ?**

I made a lot of research before posting. My linux knowledges are not very good at this time.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

EDIT #1 :

I've already tried -m32 flag but the problem still here.

For example, if I run a makefile:

```
[root@localhost makefile]# make -f sharedLib.mak
gcc -m32 -march=i686 -O2  -Wall -I ../../sharedLib/inc/ -o XXX.o -c ../src/XXX.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314,
                 from ../src/XXX.c:51:
/usr/include/sys/types.h:150: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:151: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:151: error: duplicate 'short'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:152: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
/usr/include/sys/types.h:152: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
make: *** [XXX.o] Error 1
```

Here's XXX.c:

```
#include "alphabet.h"
#include "outils.h"
#include "erreur.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> (line 51 error)
```

If a modify this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "alphabet.h"
#include "outils.h"
#include "erreur.h"
#include <string.h>
```

Everything is OK for XXX.c but the error appears for the next source file ...

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be necessary to compile a 32bit version of GCC; just supply the `-m32` flag to generate 32bit code with the 64bit version of GCC ([FAQ entry](http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/help/linux/rh_amd64_faq.html#q6)).

This question supports this: [How to compile glibc 32bit on an x86_64 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004241/how-to-compile-glibc-32bit-on-an-x86-64-machine)

Note that you might have to install 32bit versions and devel packages of all the dependencies of the code that you want to compile (i.e. linux header files, glibc, ...)

**EDIT** To debug problems like that, it's often useful to see the source which GCC tries to compile. For this, use `gcc -E` instead of `gcc -c`. That will give you the preprocessed C source plus a lot `#line` statements which tell what file GCC was reading to produce what follows.

Create such a file and examine it. The errors above make me wonder if you created a preprocessor macro which expands to something unexpected in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Thanks again.
With gcc -E, there is no error.
Everything seems to be OK during the prepocessing stage (at the end, myLib.a is created).

Comment: When running with `-E`, the code isn't compiled. You can only use the output to understand why it fails to compile! The resulting myLib.a is probably useless.